# EntityManager tries to create existing entity

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, psql, entitymanager

I'm creating an application that allows users to create hotel room reservations.

I have the entities room, user, reservation

These are my relationships set in entity class `Reservation`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private Date reservationDate;   

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Room room;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private User user;
```

When I try to save a new `Reservation` object containing an existing `User` using `EntityManager.persist()`, I get a PSQLException saying user with "id=..." violates Unique-Constraint »user_pkey«, because that user already exists. How do I tell EntitiyManager to not try to create that `User` (and `Room` at a later point too) as it already exists?

Comment: How are you setting the existing user to the Reservation object you are persisting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because JPA cascade the persist operation down to `user` which is seen as a new entity.

To prevent this:

```
reservation.setUser(entityManager.getReference(User.class, user.getId()));
```

where `getId` must be replaced accordingly.

The above code assumes you are not interested in modifying the `user`. Otherwise, a merge operation is needed:

```
reservation.setUser(entityManager.merge(user));
```